# c# make class reference immutable to other classes

Tags: c#

Can I make a class instance immutable when referenced from a specific variable, for the convenience purpose of passing it around for other classes to access its properties, but without them having access to modify it?

I know I can use read only modifier or use private set, but rather than preventing other classes from reassigning the variable I want them to have no access to modify the instance it refers to:

```
public class MetaRB

    {
        private Rigidbody2D _rb;

        // some extra metadata here
        
        public MetaRB (Rigidbody2D rigidBody)
        {
            rb = rigidBody;
        }

        public Rigidbody2D rb
        {
            get => _rb;
            private set => _rb = value;
        }
    }

    public class RigidBodyAccessor
    {
        public MetaRB metaRB;
        
        public RigidBodyAccessor(in MetaRB metaRB)
        {
            this.metaRB = metaRB;
        }

        public void Access()
        {
            var velocity = metaRB.rb.velocity; // this is allowed
        }

        public void Modify()
        {
            metaRB.rb.velocity = Vector2.zero; // make this impossible
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to have metaRB.rb.velocity imutable?

Comment: yes and all other properties of metaRB.rb, but only when accessed via this metaRB wrapper class

Comment: No, you can't. If code can get your property value then they can access any public members of that object. If that `velocity` property has a public setter then it can be set publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply return the instance, instead you have to re-implement all the properties (you need) as readonly.

```
public class MetaRB
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    public Vector2 velocity => _rb.velocity;
    public Vector2 position => _rb.position;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class Rigidbody2D with read only velocity, but when you define property with readonly, you only can set value to that property in Construtor, like as below:

```
class Rigidbody2D
{
    private readonly string _velocity;

    public string Velocity
    {
        get { return _velocity; }
    }

    public Rigidbody2D(string velocity)
    {
        _velocity = velocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also add the `sealed` modifier to the class. At that point, there's no way to mutate it (unless you use reflection).

Comment: ya, we can add the `sealed` modifier keywork to the class, if we want to prevent other classes from inheriting from it.

Comment: I don't think this applies because I think that `Rigidbody2D` is a standard Unity class.